# Subtract two text fields and show the result on a third in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I subtract first_reading from second_reading and show the total in total_reading without adding any onclick, onkeyup, onblur, etc. directly on the form field, but on the script (I won't touch the form because is a shortcode). If in jQuery, I would be needing the non-conflict code because I will be using this in Wordpress. Thank you in advance!

```
<form name="log" id="log">

<input type="text" name="first_reading" id="first_reading">
<input type="text" name="second_reading" id="second_reading">

<input type="text" name="total_reading" id="total_reading">

</form>
```

Comment: you can use AngularJS in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery in your footer.php file to archieve this , here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwkh4mL7/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("#log").length){
        $( "#first_reading" ).keyup(function() {
            $.sum();          
        }); 
        $( "#second_reading" ).keyup(function() {
            $.sum();          
        }); 
     }   
        $.sum = function(){
            $("#total_reading").val(parseInt($("#first_reading").val()) + parseInt($("#second_reading").val()));
        } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you xzegga!

I had to modify it a bit adding `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` and change the + for - sign (it was a subtraction), but finally it worked on the header of my page.

Best regards,

Ed.

Comment: No my question would be, how to avoid NaN showing up in the #total_reading field when typing...?

Comment: @LaloMárquez you can initiate inputs with 0 as value, this avoid NaN result, or you can validate these values on $.sum function before get substraction

Comment: @LaloMárquez I has updated the fiddle to avoid NaN result: http://jsfiddle.net/hwkh4mL7/4/

Comment: @zegga: thank you, how do I implement it in my code? here it is:

`<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($("#driverslog_form").length) {
        $( "#odometerstart" ).keyup(function() {
            $.sum();          
        }); 
        $( "#odometerend" ).keyup(function() {
            $.sum();          
        }); 
     }   
        $.sum = function(){
            $("#route_mileage").val(parseInt($("#odometerend").val()) - parseInt($("#odometerstart").val()));
        } 
});
/* ]]> */
</script>`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't refresh the page and I didn't saw your last reply, I'll check the fiddle, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi below is my code and I was trying to use this solution with little modification into it , your help will be much appreciated. my code does not show output but no errors.

@if (ViewBag.Admin == true)
{

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Workplan.FundingGrant, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FundingGrant, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "txt form-control", @name = "txt", @readOnly = "true", @id = "a" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FundingGrant, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Workplan.FundingGrant, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FundingGrant, new { @class = "txt form-control", @name = "txt", @id = "a" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FundingGrant, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

}


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Funding Carried Over from Previous Year", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FundingCarriedOver, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "txt form-control", @name = "txt", @id = "b" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminFee, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Admin Fee (Max of 5% of Funding Grant)", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminFee, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "txt form-control", @name = "txt", @id = "c" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminFee, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Total Funding To Be Spent In Section C", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBox("TotalFundingToBeSpentInSectionC", "", "{0:c}", new { @class = "form-control", @readOnly = "true", @value = "0.00" })
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if ($(".txt").length) {
                $("#a").keyup(function () {
                    $.sum();
                });

                $("#a").mousemove(function () {
                    $.sum();
                });

                $("#a").after(function () {
                    $.sum();
                });

                //take the input from b
                $("#b").keyup(function () {
                    $.sum();
                });

                $("#b").mousemove(function () {
                    $.sum();
                });

                $("#b").after(function () {
                    $.sum();
                });

                //take the input from c
                $("#c").keyup(function () {
                    $.sum();

                    $("#c").mousemove(function () {
                        $.sum();

                        $("#c").after(function () {
                            $.sum();
                        });
                    });
                });

                // $.sum = function () {
                function sum() {
                    var sum = 0;
                    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
                    $(".txt").each(function () {

                        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.trim().length != 0) {
                            sum = parseFloat($("#a").val()) + parseFloat($("#b").val()) - parseFloat($("#c").val());
                        }

                    });
                    if (!isNaN(sum)) {
                        document.getElementById("TotalFundingToBeSpentInSectionC").value =
                            '$' + sum.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");

                    }

                    // sum = $("#tot").val(parseFloat($("#a").val()) + parseFloat($("#b").val()) - parseFloat($("#c").val()));
                    // sum = parseFloat($("#a").val()) + parseFloat($("#b").val()) - parseFloat($("#c").val());
                    // });
                }
    </script>
```